# iOS Label is not positioned correctly over MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, position, uilabel, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video in full screen and I want to add a custom label in the center of the view.

So I'm doing something like

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("back", withExtension: "mp4")
    let player = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
    presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(player)
    player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
    player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    player.moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(player.moviePlayer.view.transform,
                                                                CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI/2)))
    player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
    player.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    player.moviePlayer.play()

    self.label.text = "Welcome."

    // Enum type, two variations:
    self.label.textAlignment = .Center
    self.label.center = self.view.center
    player.moviePlayer.view.addSubview(self.label)
```

But the result is that I have the label in the right corner, while the label.frame tell me **(139.0,273.5,42.0,21.0)**

I already tried :

```
self.view.addSubview(self.label)
```

So any suggestions ?

Comment: Do not add anything to `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view - ever! Use either the `MPMoviePlayerController.backgroundView` or the parent of `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `label` to be in the center of your `ViewController`'s view, then add it to that view. This will solve your issue:

`self.view.addSubview(self.label)` instead of adding it to the `player`.

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't appear at all. It's seem it's under the movie player.